# Automating third party access to AWS Resources

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm currently creating an open source web interface for a very CPU intensive task that's making use of other open source projects. Because it is very simple and I want to keep it open source, I don't want to bother with a revenue scheme supporting it. My plan currently is to host the site in an S3 bucket and have some simple lambda functions managing the execution delegation to the client his AWS account.

My question is, is it possible to grant access to somebody his AWS account, similar to how it works with OAuth 2.0. In an ideal world, I'd like them to see a big "authorize" button redirecting them to AWS, listing the permissions and having a confirm or deny button. Trust issues aside, [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user_externalid.html) is the only resource I could find and it looks quite cumbersome for somebody to authorize my app which in essence will only perform computations on their AWS EC2 account.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, cross account access using IAM roles is absolutely the best way to do this. [The docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_common-scenarios_third-party.html) have all the info you would need. It can be very simple for your user. The [set up instructions for Spotinst](https://help.spotinst.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005387445-Creating-your-Spotinst-account), a third party AWS service provider, demonstrate how simple it can be. They have it in four steps:

> Connect Spotinst to your Cloud Provider:
>
> 1. Click on the "Open template in Cloudformation" button and follow the instructions. Make sure to not refresh or leave this page until
>    you save your credentials.
> 2. Paste the Role ARN that was created.
> 3. Click on the "Connect account" button.

If you try it out I think you'll find it to be even easier than adding oauth to your service.